# Unable to retrieve data from firestore in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

My activity code:

```
package com.example.licenta;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListaPacienti extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    Myadapter myadapter;
    ArrayList<Pacienti> list;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_pacienti);

        //progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        //progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //progressDialog.setMessage("...");
        //progressDialog.show();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listapacienti);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        list = new ArrayList<Pacienti>();
        myadapter = new Myadapter(ListaPacienti.this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);



        EventChangeListener();
    }


    private void EventChangeListener() {
        db.collection("Nume")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                        if (error!=null){

                            Log.e("Firestore error", error.getMessage());
                            return;
                        }

                        for (DocumentChange dc: value.getDocumentChanges()){

                            if(dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                                list.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(Pacienti.class));

                            }

                            myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }


                    };
                });

    }

}
```

Adapter code:

```
package com.example.licenta;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Pacienti> list;
    
    public Myadapter(Context context, ArrayList<Pacienti> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Myadapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Pacienti pacienti = list.get(position);


        holder.nume.setText(list.get(position).getNume());
        holder.varsta.setText(list.get(position).getVarsta());
        holder.actualizare.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getActualizare()));
        //holder.varsta.setText(String.valueOf(list.varsta));
        //holder.actualizare.setText(String.valueOf(pacienti.actualizare));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView nume, varsta, actualizare;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nume=itemView.findViewById(R.id.lstnume);
            varsta=itemView.findViewById(R.id.lstvarsta);
            actualizare=itemView.findViewById(R.id.lstactualizare);
        }
    }
}
```

Class code:

```
package com.example.licenta;

public class Pacienti {

    public String nume, varsta;
    public long actualizare;

    public Pacienti(){

    }

    public Pacienti(String nume, String varsta, long actualizare) {
        this.nume = nume;
        this.varsta = varsta;
        this.actualizare = actualizare;
    }

    public String getNume() {
        return nume;
    }

    public void setNume(String nume) {
        this.nume = nume;
    }


    public String getVarsta() {
        return varsta;
    }

    public void setVarsta(String varsta) {
        this.varsta = varsta;
    }


    public long getActualizare() {
        return actualizare;
    }


    public void setActualizare(long actualizare) {
        this.actualizare = actualizare;
    }
}
```

And the firestore:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC5cj.png)

I don't know if my google-services.json is the problem.

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "825557024849",
    "project_id": "listapacienti",
    "storage_bucket": "listapacienti.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:825557024849:android:e17859e27645053a59b870",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.licenta"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "825557024849-v2kacaptlk31v3lbp7gn2pboi70bfda9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyCGkeG2qA8tSUYGV5dMjKz-RTcJAtXs1dw"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "825557024849-v2kacaptlk31v3lbp7gn2pboi70bfda9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

The app start, but doesn't show data from firebase.I tried with get() but it doesn't work.
It is a part of an app so it is possible to have this problem from another file?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No, I have no errors, but nothing is displayed on the phone and I don't know why. @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You try to retreive `actualizare` as a `long` variable while it is a `timestamp`. Try to change all the **long** to **Date** inside your class:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Pacienti {
public String nume, varsta;
public Date actualizare;

public Pacienti(){

}

public Pacienti(String nume, String varsta, Date actualizare) {
    this.nume = nume;
    this.varsta = varsta;
    this.actualizare = actualizare;
}

public String getNume() {
    return nume;
}

public void setNume(String nume) {
    this.nume = nume;
}


public String getVarsta() {
    return varsta;
}

public void setVarsta(String varsta) {
    this.varsta = varsta;
}


public Date getActualizare() {
    return actualizare;
}


public void setActualizare(Date actualizare) {
    this.actualizare = actualizare;
}
```

}

Comment: I changed that, but nothing. My phone does not display Firebase data. I don't understand why the login page worked, it recognizes my email address and password in Firebase. @Avital

Comment: @Cristina11 1. paste your xml code. 2. did you debug your full code and see that you retreive the data from Firebase correctly?

Comment: For the login and register part, the connection with firebase is OK, the data is stored and used correctly. For the part with recyclerview, where I want to get a page with a list of patients, I am not shown anything. @Avital

Comment: @Cristina11 I understand that you connect firebase correctly. But you didn't answer my question: did you debug your code and findout that you **retreive** the data correctly from Firebase? maybe some data doesn't pass ok and it stops and you don't see it. add a break point at `myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`  and see that list is full ok. Second thing, I asked you to paste your xml code